Impossible to get replies out of LLama3
As the question says, I am trying to run Llama3 but to no avail. Most people recommend using Ollama, which I cannot use due to personal circumstances (I am running the code on a cluster and I cannot install Ollama on the cluster). Another option would be to use Groq, but the problem with Groq is that it does not host custom fine-tuned models, and I would eventually like to fine-tuned LLaMa3 slightly. I suppose that, with that out of the way, I can get to the actual question.
This is my MWE:
#import relevant libraries 
import torch
from torch import cuda, bfloat16, LongTensor, FloatTensor
import transformers
import pickle 
import tqdm
import langchain
#from transformers import StoppingCriteria, StoppingCriteriaList
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, GenerationConfig
from langchain import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain import PromptTemplate,  LLMChain

#set up the basics 
auth = 'my_token'
model_id = 'meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B'
bnb_config = transformers.BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True,bnb_4bit_quant_type='nf4', 
                                             bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True, bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=bfloat16)
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id, token=auth)
terminators = [
    tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids("<|eot_id|>")

#set up model configuration and pipelines 
model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_id,token=auth)
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, cache_dir='my_folder', trust_remote_code=True,
        config=model_config, quantization_config=bnb_config,device_map='auto', token=auth)
pipe = transformers.pipeline(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16, return_full_text=True,  
    task='text-generation', eos_token_id=terminators, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id, temperature=0.1, 
    max_new_tokens=600, repetition_penalty=1.1)

#Set up simple answering chain
agent = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline = pipe)

# Prompt
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=""" <|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>system<|end_header_id|> You are a helpful assistant <|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>
    I have the following question for you: {input}  <|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>""",
    input_variables=["input"],
)

simplechain = prompt | agent 
simplechain.invoke({"input": "Where is Paris?"})


This yields nightmarish answers, such as:

I don't know. I'm not sure.
systemicketsystemicket
I have the following question for you: What's your name?   systemicket
My name is systemicket.
systemicket
I have the following question for you: What's your name?   systemicket
My name is systemicket.

I have tried everything. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help at this point would be much more than welcome.
